# Check name of MQTT topic on ESP-IDF

Tags: c, string, mqtt, esp-idf

I have a problem. I need to check if my MQTT topic is equal to a determinate string. I need to do this to do a if/else structure where I am going to stop my mqtt service or start it if I want.
I would write the topic from my mobile phone and it was received good by the ESP32.

The problem is checking the name of the topic with the "ESP_control/..."

```
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "MQTT_EVENT_DATA");
    printf("TOPIC=%.*s\r\n", event->topic_len, event->topic);
    printf("DATA=%.*s\r\n", event->data_len, event->data);

    if(strncmp(event->topic, "ESP_control/run", strlen(event->topic)) == 0) {
        if(strncmp(event->data, "STOP", strlen(event->topic)) == 0) {
            ret = esp_mqtt_client_publish(client, "ESP_control", "MQTT SERVICE STOPPED", 0, 1, 0);
                if(ret == -1) {
                    printf("ERROR sending 'MQTT SERVICE STOPPED' to topic 'ESP_control'\n");
                }
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "MQTT SERVICE STOPPED");

            esp_mqtt_client_stop(client);
        }
        else if (strncmp(event->data, "START", strlen(event->topic)) == 0) {
            esp_mqtt_client_start(client);

            ret = esp_mqtt_client_publish(client, "ESP_control", "MQTT SERVICE STARTED", 0, 1, 0);
                if(ret == -1) {
                    printf("ERROR sending 'MQTT SERVICE STARTED' to topic 'ESP_control'\n");
                }
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "MQTT SERVICE STARTED");
        }
    }
    else if(strncmp(event->topic, "ESP_control/delay", strlen(event->topic)) == 0) {
        GLOBAL_DELAY = atoi(event->data);   //  convert char* to float variable

        if(GLOBAL_DELAY > MAX_DELAY) {
            GLOBAL_DELAY = MAX_DELAY;
        }
        else if(GLOBAL_DELAY < MIN_DELAY) {
            GLOBAL_DELAY = MIN_DELAY;
        }
    }
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: You've not actually said what doesn't work with the code you have supplied. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72171175/edit) question to clearly explain what is not working.

Comment: Please add some example what data is passed to your function together with the output you expect and what you get.

Comment: Hi, when my esp received some mqtt message it enters in this function, execute lines 2 and 3, but the if/else dont work... I think it is probably the comprobating of strncmp. It would probably be because event->topic is char* and I am equaling with a single char??

Comment: Again: Please show sample data yout get when this function is called. (Real complete strings, not some shortened version)

Comment: What is the purpose of `strncmp` instead of `strcmp`? Do you want to receive topics that are a prefix to your strings or do you want your string literals to be prefixes? `strncmp(event->topic, "ESP_control/run", strlen(event->topic))` will match if `topic` holds plain `"ESP"`

Comment: I want to check if my topic is literally: "ESP_control/run"... I have used strncmp to include the length of the string; using strcmp I have obtained the same result... Are you saying that using this my strcmp/strncmp is checking if "ESP" == "ESP_control/run" ???

Comment: If you limit the length of `strncmp` to the length of the topic, it will match for any prefix. Especially it will match with `ESP_control` without sub topics. If you want to check for exact match, why use `strncmp`? That's a waste of time. This function is only useful to check for prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution yesterday, it's basically use a for loop to write a new array using the `client->event_len` for the condition. I will show you:

```
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "MQTT_EVENT_DATA");
    printf("TOPIC=%.*s\r\n", event->topic_len, event->topic);
    printf("DATA=%.*s\r\n", event->data_len, event->data);

    for(i = 0; i <= event->topic_len; i++) {
        if(i == event->topic_len) read_topic[i] = '\0';
        else read_topic[i] = event->topic[i];
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= event->data_len; i++) {
        if(i == event->data_len) read_data[i] = '\0';
        else read_data[i] = event->data[i];
    }

    //printf("%s\n%.*s\n\n%s\n%.*s\n\n", read_topic, event->topic_len, event->topic, read_data, event->data_len, event->data);

    if(strcmp(read_topic, "ESP_control/run") == 0) {
        if(strcmp(read_data, "STOP") == 0) {
            ret = esp_mqtt_client_publish(client, "ESP_control", "MQTT SERVICE STOPPED", 0, 1, 0);
                if(ret == -1) {
                    printf("ERROR sending 'MQTT SERVICE STOPPED' to topic 'ESP_control'\n");
                }
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "MQTT SERVICE STOPPED");

            ret = esp_mqtt_client_stop(client);
            printf("ERROR stopping MQTT client: %x\n", ret);
        }
        else if (strcmp(read_data, "START") == 0) {
            ret = esp_mqtt_client_start(client);
            if(ret != ESP_OK) {
                ret = esp_mqtt_client_reconnect(client);
                if(ret != ESP_OK) {
                    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "ERROR reconnecting MQTT client!!!");
                }
            }

            ret = esp_mqtt_client_publish(client, "ESP_control", "MQTT SERVICE STARTED", 0, 1, 0);
                if(ret == -1) {
                    printf("ERROR sending 'MQTT SERVICE STARTED' to topic 'ESP_control'\n");
                }
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "MQTT SERVICE STARTED");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use sprintf() instead of for().

```
....
sprintf(read_topic, "%.*s", event->topic_len, event->topic);
sprintf(read_data, "%.*s", event->data_len, event->data);
....
```